# How do I create percentage from total amount in r studio

Tags: r, dataframe

First I get a total amount for each category.

```
table <- my_data %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(count))
table
```

my result -

```
  Category      Total
   <chr>         <dbl>
 1 Date Range        5
 2 None             87
 3 Product           1
 4 Reset             2
```

what I want to do next is get a percentage of each category compared to the total.

I try like this.

```
irisNew <- table %>% group_by(Total) %>% 
  summarize(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(pct = count/sum(count))  # find percent of total
irisNew
```

but it gives me

```
 Total count   pct
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1     3   0.3
2     2     1   0.1
3     3     1   0.1
4     5     1   0.1
```

I want something that gets percentage of each category compared to total amount

```
  Category      Total        Percent
   <chr>         <dbl>
 1 Date Range        5           %
 2 None             87           %
 3 Product           1           %
 4 Reset             2           %
```

Answer (score 3):

From the `table`, we can divide the `sum` of 'Total' after `ungroup`ing

```
library(dplyr)
table %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(Percent = 100 * Total/sum(Total))
```

-output

```
#   Category Total   Percent
#1 Date Range     5  5.263158
#2       None    87 91.578947
#3    Product     1  1.052632
#4      Reset     2  2.105263
```

NOTE: `table` is a function name.  It is better to avoid naming objects with function names

#### data

```
table <- structure(list(Category = c("Date Range", "None", "Product", 
"Reset"), Total = c(5L, 87L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```